# jQuery loop JSON with intervals

Tags: jquery, json, loops

I am trying to set an interval between each JSON element. 
This JSON will print in the page some tweets taken from an API endpoint.

The problem is that the below function is not working. For some reasons it waits the amount of time I declared in the timing function, but after having waited it prints the very last tweet in the JSON instead of printing them one by one with the interval I declared.

I tried with both `setTimeout` and `setInterval` with no luck.

The goal is to show a tweet every TOT seconds from the JSON response.

Here is the API endpoint:`xxxx/tweets.php`

Here is my function:

```
function tweets() {
    $.when(getData(tweetsEndpoint)).done(function(json) {
        $.each(json.twitter, function(k, v) {
            $.each(v, function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    tweetId = v.id;
                    tweetName = v.nom;
                    tweetUser = v.lien_twitter;
                    tweetImg = v.image;
                    tweetDate = v.date;
                    tweet = v.twitt;
                    tweetAuthor = v.author_type;
                    if (tweetAuthor === 'user') {
                        console.log('user');
                        $('#p31_bubble_right').html('');
                        obj = $('#p31_bubble_right').append(makeTweet(k, tweetUser, tweetAuthor, tweet));
                        obj.fitText(7.4);
                        $('#p31_bubble_left').html('');
                    } else {
                        $('#p31_bubble_left').html('');
                        obj = $('#p31_bubble_left').append(makeTweet(k, tweetUser, tweetAuthor, tweet));
                        obj.fitText(7.4);
                        $('#p31_bubble_right').html('');
                        console.log('operator');
                    }
                }, tweetSwitcher);
            });
        });

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.each(json.twitter, function(k, v) {
    $.each(v, function() {
                 //   ^---- You need to use the index,element arguments
         setTimeout(function() {
              tweetId = v.id;
```

You're not passing through `v` to the second `$.each`, or at least, you're still accessing the array `v` rather than the individual item.

**EDIT** Just looked at the response from your API.

I think you've got too many `$.each`'s. Remove the second one. `v` isn't an array of objects, it's the object you're after.

```
$.each(json.twitter, function(index,element){
  setTimeout(function(){

    console.log(element.twitt);

  }, tweetSwitcher * index); 
});
```

Comment: No change at all. Can you provide the code sample? I am a little lost here

Comment: @DiegoPucci - Seems you were iterating too many times. Check my update.

Comment: Yes I was iterating too many times, but still not the expected result. It still starts from the last JSON element and does not set an interval between each loop

Comment: Although I hinted at it, it may not have been clear enough. You can multiply `tweetSwitcher` (which I assume is the time in milliseconds) by `index` to create a stagger effect.